What type of aura component is this?
Here you can see I've created two custom components that show your own open opps and tasks when viewing your own user record page but they show someone else's when you're viewing theirs.
I cloned the code for the open opps datatable to make the tasks datatable. But I don't want the tasks to be in a datatable, I want them to be in whatever type of aura component the defaults are in (circled). What is that? It doesn't look like a list.

